# how to print values from 2 arrays in a correct format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays as shown below. The first array contains only 2 fields **Email ID, Address** in a repeating manner.

```
arr1 = [
  " Email ID: md@floretmedia.com",
  "# 361, 7TH CROSS, 1ST BLOCK JAYANAGAR, BANGALORE KA 560011 IN",
  " Email ID: santhosh@thidff.com",
  "# 46/4, Garvebhavi Playa kudul gate, Hossur Rd, Begur hobali bangalore Bangalore KA 560068 IN",
  " Email ID: rajiv.sawhney@flipkart.com",
  "Vaishnavi Summit, Ground Floor, 7th Main, 80 Feet Road, 3rd Block, Koramangala Industrial Layout, Bangalore KA 560034 IN", " Email ID: sachinjain@justdial.com",
  "PALM COURT BLDG.- M, 501/B, 5TH FL, NEW LINK RD. BESIDE GOREGAON SPORTS COMPLEX MALAD WEST MH 400064 IN", " Email ID: -", "MALANCHA ROAD KHARAGPUR MIDNAPUR WB 000000 IN"
];
```

My second array contains three fields, **Id, Name, Date** as shown:

```
arr2 = [
  "05141859", " MURUGESAN DHANAPAL", "22 December 2011",
  "06372276", " RAJESWARI GOMATHINAYAGAM", "04 December 2012",
  "01815226", " RAJIV SAWHNEY", "11 April 2016",
  "00202052", " VENKATACHALAM STHANU SUBRAMANI", "05 December 2006"
];
```

My desired output is:

```
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th> Name</th>
  <th>date</th>
  <th>Email Id</th>Address
  <th></th>
</tr>'
```

I'm using this code:

```
$.each(arr1, function(i) {
  content += '<tr><td>' + arr[i % 2] + '</td><td>' + arr[i + 1] + '</td><td>' + arr[i + 2] + '</td>';
  return false;
});

$.each(cont, function(i) {
  content += '<td>' + cont[i % 2] + '</td><td>' + cont[i % 2 + 1] + '</td></tr>';

  return false;
});
```

Comment: You might want to read and heed the [online help on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Data structure should be changed in the first place. Doesn't make sense to workaround such a clumsy one. Not interesting.

Comment: you need a unique information (ID) to reference one element in array 1 to another element in array 2. this is called a JOIN ...unless it's ordered and indices suffice!

Comment: thank you @eisbehr for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK let me give you not just the headers but the whole table. I use a generic function `tableMaker` to get the table HTML. It takes an array of objects. Each object represent a row while the properties are obviouslt the headers. `tableMaker` takes two arguments like `tableMaker(tableData,true)` if second argument is true the headers are displayed otherwise not displayed.

```js
function tableMaker(o,h){
  var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
      rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
}

var data1 = [" Email ID: md@floretmedia.com","# 361, 7TH CROSS, 1ST BLOCK JAYANAGAR, BANGALORE KA 560011 IN",
              " Email ID: santhosh@thidff.com", "# 46/4, Garvebhavi Playa kudul gate, Hossur Rd, Begur hobali bangalore Bangalore KA 560068 IN",
              " Email ID: rajiv.sawhney@flipkart.com","Vaishnavi Summit, Ground Floor, 7th Main, 80 Feet Road, 3rd Block, Koramangala Industrial Layout, Bangalore KA 560034 IN",
              " Email ID: sachinjain@justdial.com","PALM COURT BLDG.- M, 501/B, 5TH FL, NEW LINK RD. BESIDE GOREGAON SPORTS COMPLEX MALAD WEST MH 400064 IN",
              " Email ID: -", "MALANCHA ROAD KHARAGPUR MIDNAPUR WB 000000 IN"
            ].reduce((data,e,i) => !(i%2) ? data.concat({"Email ID": e.split(":")[1].trim()})
                                          : (data[data.length-1].Address = e, data) ,[]),
    data2 = ["05141859", " MURUGESAN DHANAPAL", "22 December 2011",
             "06372276", " RAJESWARI GOMATHINAYAGAM", "04 December 2012",
             "01815226", " RAJIV SAWHNEY", "11 April 2016",
             "00202052", " VENKATACHALAM STHANU SUBRAMANI", "05 December 2006"
            ].reduce((data,e,i) => i%3 === 0 ? data.concat({"Id": e})
                                             : i%3 === 1 ? (data[data.length-1].Name = e.trim(), data)
                                                         : (data[data.length-1].Date = e, data),[]),
tableData = data2.map((o,i) => Object.assign({},o,data1[i])),
tableHTML = tableMaker(tableData,true);
myTable.innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying that the best way to fix this should be improving how your data is structured in the first place, but if that is not possible try something like:

```
var i = 0;
var $table = $("<table>");
while (2 * i < arr1.length && 3 * i < arr2.length) {
  $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(arr1[2 * i])).append($("<td>").text(arr1[2 * i + 1])).append($("<td>").text(arr2[3 * i])).append($("<td>").text(arr2[3 * i + 1])).append($("<td>").text(arr2[3 * i + 2])).appendTo($table);
  i++;
}
$table.appendTo("#tableHolder");
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2uwp8vL1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```js
var arr1 = [
  " Email ID: md@floretmedia.com",
  "# 361, 7TH CROSS, 1ST BLOCK JAYANAGAR, BANGALORE KA 560011 IN",
  " Email ID: santhosh@thidff.com",
  "# 46/4, Garvebhavi Playa kudul gate, Hossur Rd, Begur hobali bangalore Bangalore KA 560068 IN",
  " Email ID: rajiv.sawhney@flipkart.com",
  "Vaishnavi Summit, Ground Floor, 7th Main, 80 Feet Road, 3rd Block, Koramangala Industrial Layout, Bangalore KA 560034 IN", " Email ID: sachinjain@justdial.com",
  "PALM COURT BLDG.- M, 501/B, 5TH FL, NEW LINK RD. BESIDE GOREGAON SPORTS COMPLEX MALAD WEST MH 400064 IN", " Email ID: -", "MALANCHA ROAD KHARAGPUR MIDNAPUR WB 000000 IN"
];

var arr2 = [
  "05141859", " MURUGESAN DHANAPAL", "22 December 2011",
  "06372276", " RAJESWARI GOMATHINAYAGAM", "04 December 2012",
  "01815226", " RAJIV SAWHNEY", "11 April 2016",
  "00202052", " VENKATACHALAM STHANU SUBRAMANI", "05 December 2006"
];

var count = arr2.length;
var j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < count; i = i + 3) {
  $('#print tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + arr2[i] + '</td><td>' + arr2[i + 1] + '</td><td>' + arr2[i + 2] + '</td><td>' + arr1[j] + '</td><td>' + arr1[j + 1] + '</td></tr>');
  j = j + 2;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="print">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Email Id</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by converting to an array of objects. I'm calling them `records` here.

```
interface Record {
  id:      string;
  name:    string;
  date:    string;
  emailId: string;
  address: string;
}
```

This iterates over groups of `step` items in an array. Each time it's called it will return the next `step` items. It returns `null` when there are no more items.

```
function makeGroupIterator(array, step) {
  var index = 0;
  return function () {
    if (index + step >= array.length) {
      return null;
    }
    var group = array.slice(index, index + step);
    index += step;
    return group;
  };
}
```

This takes both of your arrays and converts them into the record structure.

```
function convertToRecords(arr1, arr2) {

  var records = [];

  var nextArr1Group = makeGroupIterator(arr1, 2);
  var nextArr2Group = makeGroupIterator(arr2, 3);

  while (true) {

    var group1 = nextArr1Group();
    var group2 = nextArr2Group();
    if (!group1 || !group2) {
      break;
    }

    records.push({
      id:      group2[0],
      name:    group2[1],
      date:    group2[2],
      emailId: group1[0],
      address: group1[1]
    });
  }
  return records;
}
```

This takes the record array and converts it into an html string.

```
function formatRecords(records) {
  var content = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var r = records[i];
    content += [
      "<tr>",
        "<td>", r.id ,     "</th>",
        "<td>", r.name,    "</td>",
        "<td>", r.date,    "</td>",
        "<td>", r.emailId, "</td>",
        "<td>", r.address, "</td>",
      "</tr>"
    ].join("");
  }
  return content;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var arr1 = [
  " Email ID: md@floretmedia.com",
  "# 361, 7TH CROSS, 1ST BLOCK JAYANAGAR, BANGALORE KA 560011 IN",
  " Email ID: santhosh@thidff.com",
  "# 46/4, Garvebhavi Playa kudul gate, Hossur Rd, Begur hobali bangalore Bangalore KA 560068 IN",
  " Email ID: rajiv.sawhney@flipkart.com",
  "Vaishnavi Summit, Ground Floor, 7th Main, 80 Feet Road, 3rd Block, Koramangala Industrial Layout, Bangalore KA 560034 IN", " Email ID: sachinjain@justdial.com",
  "PALM COURT BLDG.- M, 501/B, 5TH FL, NEW LINK RD. BESIDE GOREGAON SPORTS COMPLEX MALAD WEST MH 400064 IN", " Email ID: -", "MALANCHA ROAD KHARAGPUR MIDNAPUR WB 000000 IN"
];

var arr2 = [
  "05141859", " MURUGESAN DHANAPAL", "22 December 2011",
  "06372276", " RAJESWARI GOMATHINAYAGAM", "04 December 2012",
  "01815226", " RAJIV SAWHNEY", "11 April 2016",
  "00202052", " VENKATACHALAM STHANU SUBRAMANI", "05 December 2006"
];

var records = convertToRecords(arr1, arr2);
var html = formatRecords(records);
console.log(html)
```

Comment: what you are saying is correct but iam filtering those things from website inside variables tags like <b>,<p>,<strong>. and some times it contains more fields.

Answer (score 0):

Run here: http://www.es6fiddle.net/is65fafa/

Concur that your data format is not great.  But sometimes we can't control it.  If you want to do more with this data, would suggest object-ifying it.  But if this is for one-time use:

```
let s = arr2.filter((e,i) => i%3 === 0).map((e,i) =>
  `<tr>
    <td>${arr2[i*3]}</td>
    <td>${arr2[i*3+1]}</td>
    <td>${arr2[i*3+2]}</td>
    <td>${arr1[i*2]}</td>
    <td>${arr1[i*2+1]}</td>
   </tr>` ).join('')
```

Comment: my dear brother your code is working finely,i have implemented your code for my project.  but i got correct answer before yours, which involved a lot of effort. so please dont mind.

Comment: thank @josh for such a great answer and is very much scalable

Comment: @user5405873 Though you can only mark one answer as "accepted," you should still upvote any answer that you find useful.  This is the way stack overflow works.  Five people here took the time and effort to help you, and so far you have not upvoted any answers, and I would encourage you to do so if you value the information you have received.

Comment: sorry iam there,now i have